# Add a TextBox as the last element of an ItemsControl with WrapPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, itemscontrol

I am trying to implement the following scanarios
  [image]

**APPROACH SO FAR**

Tried to implement it with an ItemsControl (with WrapPanel) and a TextBox wrapped inside a WrapPanel, but it does not have a desired output as there are two WrapPanels wrapping separately

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding someThing}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <Grid>
                       <Border>
                           <TextBlock Text="somesomething" />
                       </Border>
                   </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
      <TextBox/>
 </toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

I am thinking if I can add the TextBox at the END of the ItemsControl, but failed to do so. Please specify if there is any other workaround/ solution to any of my approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DataTemplateSelector` for the `ItemsControl` and specify different templates for different list items.

```
public class BlockItem
{
    // TODO
}

public class BoxItem
{
    // TODO
}

public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate BlockTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate BoxTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        if (item is BlockItem) return BlockTemplate;
        else if (item is BoxItem) return BoxTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding someObject}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:MyTemplateSelector>
            <local:MyTemplateSelector.BlockTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="something"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyTemplateSelector.BlockTemplate>
            <local:MyTemplateSelector.BoxTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Text="something"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyTemplateSelector.BoxTemplate>
        </local:MyTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ItemsControl>
```

And you then add different types of objects to your items source:

```
someObject.Add(new BlockItem());
someObject.Add(new BlockItem());
someObject.Add(new BlockItem());
someObject.Add(new BlockItem());
someObject.Add(new BoxItem());
```

If you want the `TextBox` to be the last element, then you need it to be the last item in your `ItemsSource` list.